# RMagick 2.16.0 error (on gem install)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

**upon gem install:**

```
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/yonatan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/yonatan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/yonatan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
```

**looking in mkmf log I get:**
Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. You must have ImageMagick 6.4.9 or later.

**And my imagemagick version is**
imagemagick:
  Installed: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-3ubuntu1.2

**Im running on Ubuntu 17.04.
Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to make sure that you have any ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9 and < 7.0.0. RMagick is **not compatible with ImageMagick 7** as of Nov 2018. I'll update this answer if that happens. You can run `convert --version` to see which one you have.

Next, RMagick needs ImageMagick *and* some of its dev headers. Since you're on Ubuntu, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Then run `gem install rmagick` (or your bundle command) again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with MagickCore.pc file

For anyone having the same issue - simply locate the path to this file and add it to the .bashrc file as an export

for example:
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue under Centos. It only required to install ImageMagick-devel via:

`sudo yum install ImageMagick-devel`